# Promises: chain methods and work with both returned objects?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have this code:

```
return (entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id, ....))
    .then((list) => {
        // party with list object!
        return {
            list: list
        }
    }
```

And I want to call another method as well, `entity.Tag.getAllForUser`, which returns a `tags` list.

(UPDATE: I need to do this using promises only - I can't use async/await.)

This code doesn't work - it says both `list` and `tag` are undefined:

```
return (entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id, ....))
    .then((list) => entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id))
    .then((list, tags) => {
        // party with both list and tags objects!
        return {
            list: list,
            tags: tags
        }
    }
```

I've also tried chaining the second call onto the first:

```
return (
    entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id, ....).then((list) => 
    entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id))
 ).then((list, tags) => {
    // party with both list and tags objects!
    return {
        list: list,
        tags: tags
    }
}
```

But again it says `list` is undefined. What *does* work?

Comment: Why do you have multiple returns?

Comment: @chevybow because I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Your title says "chain methods", but why would you need *chaining* at all?

Comment: @trincot Possibly I don't! I need to execute both, and use the results of both. Sorry for not being more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon wether you requests are **independent** or not:

#### Get multiple resolved values on independent requests:

Let's say I have `getUsers()` and `getCities()`, and both are independent (you don't need the users to get the cities and viceversa). Then you can use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([getUsers(), getCities()])
.then(result => {
  // result here will be an array of two elements:
  // result[0] -> what getUsers resolves
  // result[1] -> what getCities resolves 
});
```

#### Get multiple resolved values on dependent requests:

If you have, let's say, `getUser()`, which returns an user, and then `getCouple(user)`, which returns a person related to an user, and then `getHouse(user1, user2)`, which happens to need both of them, you can do the following:

```
const user = getUser();
const couple = user.then(u => getCouple(u)); // you can reuse a promise. This does not trigger then handler again, if
// the promise is settled will yield the settle value.
const house = user.then(u => {
  return couple.then(c => {
    return getHouse(u,c);
  });
});
```

This gets much nicer with async/await:

```
async function() {
  const user = await getUser();
  const couple = await getCouple(user);
  const house = await getHouse(user, couple);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the clearest explanation I've seen anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use `Async/Await`

```
let list = await entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id, ....))
let tags = await entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id))

return {
        list: list,
        tags: tags
    }
}
```

If you can't use `Async/Await` ( even though i recommend using them ) you can use promise.all

```
Promise.all([
   entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id),
   entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id);
 ]).then(([list,tag])=>{
   // do here whatever you want
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That would be the simplest way, but unfortunately I can't do this, because the codebase I'm working in doesn't allow it. (Have updated question to clarify this.)

Comment: @Richard you can use `promise.all` even though i will still recommend using `asyc/await` which makes code more readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is `Promise.all`, which takes a list of promises, and returns a list of the resolved values:

```
return Promise.all([
  entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id),
  entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id);
])
  .then(([ list, tags ]) => {
    // Party!
    return { list, tags };
  });
```

Obligatory recommendation to use `async` and `await`:

```
let [ list, tags ] = await Promise.all([
  entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id),
  entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id);
]);

return { list, tags };
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question. Please don't delete, as this may be useful for someone else!

```
return (entity.User.getProjects(req.user.id, ....))
    .then((list) => Promise.all([list, entity.Tag.getAllForUser(req.user.id)]))
    .then(([list, tags]) => {
        // party with both list and tags objects!
        return {
            list: list,
            tags: tags
        }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using `Promise.all` to run both queries at the same time! Your solution here will unnecessarily run things serially.